# Is it possible to activate office 2013 trail version with Professional Key

Tags: installation, ms-office, office-2013

Due to some third-party software, we have to install office in the 32 bit Version, but it must not be in a path with "(" or ")" in it (This is an issue with an oracle client, and we definitely can not change here). 
So when we tried office 2013 and therefore simply bought an single "Home and Business" license, we soon recognized that with the (Irony on) wonderful (Irony off) Click-to-Run Installer we can not achieve this. After hours with the Microsoft support, we found out that the msi Installer for Office 2013 we need for this, is only shipped with volume licenses.
Since we do not want volume licenses, I did a little research, and found out that some people that need to change the path of the install location, installed the trial version of office which comes with the msi Installer, and then activated it.
So my question is: Which license key do I need to activate the trial. The trial itself is "Professional Plus", but can I activate it with a "Professional" license? Since "Professional Plus" only seems available via volume licensing, which we still do not want...

I hope somebody had similar issues, and knows a solution. The Microsoft support simply does not know anything on this, but want to sell me an 300€ Tech.Ticket...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After another hours and hours I spend with the Microsoft Support I clearly got the Statement this is not possible.
It is even not possible to activate the trial with a key you purchase by clicking on the buy button in the yellow pane that informs you this is just a Trial. (Beside your buying the full pro plus Version).
Maybe oneday somebody will face the same Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well the steps I followed for activating was
 Click on License Options -> Convert to Full.
It'll ask you to buy a new product key of final version of Office 2013 or enter the product key if you have already purchased it. Just click on "Enter Key" button:
Though its not possible to activate a Professional Plus with Professional license.
Try to buy a key from activation page.